# Why do I see a 'Yay' with a 70% match, and a 'Booo' with a 75% match?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-shares

Just what the title states.

I'm just a couple of days into this idle CPU utilization thing; I run a CPU miner (x-coin-minerd on a Windows 7 box).

Scrolling through the command line output I see several lines that say 'accepted' - some show a 'Yay', whilst others show a 'Booo'. Yet some 'Yay' show a lower match (70%), and some 'Boo' show a higher match (>75%).

(The previous entries were lost, but the most recent Yay/Boo visible on the command line are posted below for reference)

> [2014-06-24 08:37:25] accepted: 14/15 (93.33%), 89.76 khash/s (booooo)
>
> [2014-06-24 08:37:45] accepted: 15/16 (93.75%), 89.75 khash/s (yay!!!)

Why do I see a 'Yay' with a 70% match, and a 'Booo' with a 75% match?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it shows "booooo" when a share is rejected, and "yay!!!" when a share is accepted.

In `x/y (z%)`

- **`x`** is the number of accepted shares
- **`y`** is the number of total shares submitted (accepted+rejected)
- **`z`** is `x/y` as a percentage (the percent that are accepted)

> Why do I see a 'Yay' with a 70% match, and a 'Booo' with a 75% match?

Because you had a success which raised you to a 70% success rate, and later (after a few more successes) had a rejection which lowered you to a 75% success rate.

(BTW, I hope you know that mining any SHA256 or Scrypt coin on a CPU is almost certain to cost you more than it can earn you)

Comment: It might be worthwhile explaining what it means when a share is "accepted" vs. "rejected", and why this distinction exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'll back up his (BTW, I hope you know that mining any SHA256 coin on a CPU is almost certain to cost you more than it can earn you)

I'm mining it with a usb gekkoscience asic at 23,000,000,000  23gigahash, and getting 4 1 cent an hour..

the only reason I'm actualy earning anything is I'm only going through 2.5 watts of power...

your probably going through 100's :-(